# What is the Regular Expression that Enables Press the Enter Key to Exit a Loop (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

What is the regex that allows the 'Enter' key event (pressing the Enter key) as the only acceptable input? I want to be able to skip an 'optional' `input()` statement (e.g. `middleName = input("Enter middle name (Optional): ") (for those who have no middle name or don't want to enter their middle name))` by pressing the 'Enter' key to proceed to a required `input()` statement (e.g. `lastName = input("Enter last name: ")`). The Empty String regex does not work for me because it does not `'restrict'` acceptable input to the 'Enter' key event only; it allows all characters (e.g. `numbers, special characters`) entered by the user to be stored in the variable (e.g. middleName). I want to handle all non-alphabet characters as invalid inputs, except those I allow in a regex (e.g. `apostrophe, hyphen, white space`), if the user inputs a non-alphabet character.

Here's my code:

```
import re

print('Political Elections Voter Eligibility\n\n')

pattern1 = "^[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+'[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]"
pattern2 = "^[A-Z]|^[A-Z].|^[A-Z]+'[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]"
pattern3 = "^[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+'[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]|^[A-Z]+ [A-Z]|^[A-Z]+ [A-Z]."

while True:
    
    firstName = input("Enter your first name and tap or click 'Enter': ")
    
    print('\n')

    if re.search(pattern1, firstName):
        
        break

    else:
        
        print('\n')
        
        print('Invalid entry.')

while True:
    
    middleName = input("Enter your middle name or middle initial and tap or click 'Enter' (Optional): ")

    print('\n')

    if re.search(pattern2, middleName):

        break

    else:
        
        print('\n')

        print('Invalid entry.')

while True:
    
    lastName = input("Enter your last name and tap or click 'Enter': ")

    print('\n')

    if re.search(pattern3, lastName):
        
        break

    else:
        
        print('\n')

        print('Invalid entry.')
```

while True:

```
try:
    age = int(input("Enter your age and tap or click 'Enter': "))

except ValueError:
    
    print('\n')
    
    print('Invalid entry.')
    
    continue

print('\n')

if 1 <= age <= 125:
    
    if 1 <= age <= 17:
        print('%s %s %s, age %s, you are not eligible to vote in political elections.' % (firstName, middleName, lastName, age))
        
        break

    if 18 <= age <= 125:
        print('%s %s %s, age %s, you are eligible to vote in political elections.' % (firstName, middleName, lastName, age))
        
        break

else:
    print('Invalid entry.')
```

Comment: Hello @Jeremy ... could you also please paste your code that you have worked of so far... Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Ice Bear ...Okay

Comment: Have you tried the regex `^$`? `^` is the start of line delimiter and `$` is the end of line. The pattern only matches an empty string.

Comment: Hello @HåkenLid ...I use ^ to restrict the first letter in the name to uppercase

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, there is a more simple scenario to achieve your target. If you modify the `if` statement in the case of `middleName`.

from

```
    if re.search(pattern2, middleName):
```

to

```
    if len(middleName)==0 or re.search(pattern2, middleName):
```

so the code become(in the code related to `middleName`):

```
while True:
    
    middleName = input("Enter your middle name or middle initial and tap or click 'Enter' (Optional): ")

    print('\n')

    if len(middleName)==0 or re.search(pattern2, middleName):

        break

    else:
        
        print('\n')

        print('Invalid entry.')
```

Comment: Thanks @Nour-Allah Hussein ...I had to change =0 to ==0. It works perfect! Thank you so much! :-)